# Set cookie value to formio dropdown list while form loading using angular or javascript or formIo

Tags: javascript, angular, formio

I am using formio form in angular APPlication.
I have registration form in my application with several fields. In the registration form i have Sate and city dropdowns. And the state and city dropdowns values are loading from State and city formio resources.
When user click on Register link while loading the form, I want to assign the state and city dropdown values from cookie variables.

I have the logic to assign load cookie variables.
But i am not able to assign state and city dropdown values from cookie variables.
please suggest any solution to implement cookies in form io forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `customDefaultValue` and `calculatedValue` properties allow you to execute JavaScript, including calls to Web APIs like `localStorage`. One possible solution here is to set a `customDefaultValue` for the select component that reads from `localStorage` and an `change` event handler that writes the selected value to `localStorage`.

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/brendanbond/L04195tz/20/